# Mapping different native queries result to same POJO with same SqlResultSetMapping?

Tags: java, jpa-2.1, sqlresultsetmapping

I need to execute several different queries and I want to use the same POJO to get the results. What I get with those queries are combinations of same columns, can I reuse the same `sqlResultSetMapping`?

I am working with JPA-2.1 and Java 8

My queries are something like:

```
select tableA.a, tableB.b, tableA.c
from tableA
inner join tableB

select tableA.a, tableB.b
from tableA
inner join tableB

select tableB.b, tableA.c
from tableA
inner join tableB
```

My POJO is something like:

```
public class Result {
 String a;
 String b;
 String c;
}
```

and finally, my SqlResultSetMapping is:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="GeneralResult",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Result.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name="a", type=String.class),                             @ColumnResult(name="b", type=String.class),     @ColumnResult(name="c", type=String.class)
                        }
                )
        }
)
```

When I execute the first query, with fields a,b, the call works fine. The problem is when I execute one of the other two queries.

Can I use the same `SqlResultSetMapping` for those queries?

I tried with several ConstructorResult but the problem is all fields are String (VARCHAR in DB).

Thanks in advance.